# Autocomplete textview changes height while scrolling through items

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am facing a problem while using autocomplete textview .
It looks like it is changing its height to full screen when i scroll the options of autocomplete textview.
I dont want that to be happen.

This figures will give you actual idea.

**before scrolling**

[image]

**after scrolling**

[image]